# I am to login on web-page on share-point site but when i try to access from C# getting wrong username or email Id error

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, .net, core-api

Below is my C# code which I am using for connect SharePoint site.

When I try to access same SharePoint site from web page it's working fine and I able to access it
But when I try to with below code I am getting error.

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: 'The sign-in name or
>   password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.'

```
string targetSiteURL = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/SD/";


                var login = "ka.pa@test.onmicrosoft.com";
                var password = "password";
                SecureString securePass = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
            {
                securePass.AppendChar(c);
            }

            //AuthenticationManager am = new AuthenticationManager();
            //using (var cc = am.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(targetSiteURL, login, securePass))
            //{
            //    cc.ExecuteQuery();
            //    var count = cc.Web.Lists.Count;

            //}

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
            context.RequestTimeout = -1;
            context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

            Web web = context.Web;



            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePass);

            try
            {
                context.Load(web);
                //context.ExecuteQueryAsync();

                context.ExecuteQuery();
                //context.ExecuteQueryAsync().Wait();
                //var str = "true";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var error = e.ToString();
            }
```

Before asking question here, I spend a lot of time on it but i didn't get any solution.
If any one know the solution of it then that is very helpful for me.

Notes- I am using below packages in C#.

[image]

Comment: Is there multi-factor authentication enabled for this tenant?

Comment: @GaneshSanap No not enable for this tenant.

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you please help if you have any idea.

Comment: Is _Modern Auth_ enabled for SPO? The answer is likely "yes" as all tenants created within the past couple of years have had it enabled by default. You should be using a client id/secret pattern, not username and password.